# Meaning of two minus signs together ("double unary")

Tags: excel, excel-formula, operators

What does the two `-` sign mean at the beginning of a formula?

Ex:
This formula gets a string date and converts it into an Excel date serial number:

```
=--(MID(S2,4,3)&LEFT(S2,3)&MID(S2,7,4))
```

The formula works fine, I just want to understand the `--` in the formula.

Comment: It's a double negative. It forces Excel to do math on the results of the rest of the formula. This can be used to convert Boolean results (true or false) to a number (1 or 0) or, possible in the case of this formula, to force the results of all this string manipulation to be a number. You could also use something like `=0+(MID(S2,4,3)&LEFT(S2,3)&MID(S2,7,4))`, but `--` is pretty standard for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JNevill's Comment seems a good answer to me but for the sake of an Answer consider `Y` in A1 and `Y` in B1. This formula:

```
=(A1=B1)
```

returns TRUE. As mentioned, stick an operator in front (with `0+`, or `1*`) and the Boolean is turned into `1`, or `0` if B1 (only) is changed to, say, `X`.

The single minus negates that. `0-`, or `-1*`, at the front returns `-1` for both A1 and B1 equal to `Y`. Negate *that* and the `-1` result becomes `1`, say with  `=--1*(A1=B1)`.

But then multiplying by one (or adding zero) is pointless, might as well just go for:

```
=--(A1=B1)
```

Note that because of the order in which the evaluations take place, the above is not the same as:

```
=--A1=B1
```

which has no meaning so returns `#VALUE!`.

Text functions (`MID` and `LEFT` in your example) return strings, so constructing a date index for today for example (42311 in the 1900 date system) with such functions (alone) returns five characters Excel does not recognise as possibly representing a date. Converted to numeric format and represented as a date this should look like 'today'.

So format a cell as Text and enter 42311, then reformat as Date and the result is still `42311`. Format a cell as General and enter:

```
=--("42"&"311")
```

before then formatting as Date and you should see something that looks like 'today'.

Comment: You can also use the `N` function to accomplish the same thing. `=N("a"="a")` should result in `1`, etc.

Comment: Hahah yeah your answer is plenty adequate, just wanted to provide the other alternative way of doing that. I feel like the `N` function is not well-known :)