# Three variables (columns) to be combined in one variable (column)

Tags: database, excel, statistics

[image: [1]]
 demo data

Either in Excel or in Statistical Package for the Social Science:

To combine the three columns into one and to be able then to calculate the statistics of the column. Mean, Median, Mode frequencies and all these.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?
If you compute the mean of the three the values combined (not added), what are you expecting this to tell you? As far as I can tell this will just be an effectively random number...

Comment: P.s. Excel and SPSS are not 'databases' so you should probably change the tag to either Excel, SPSS, or statistics....

Comment: Please, consider posting your attamps to solve described problem. Are there any? Any of them didn't worked for you as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I too have no idea why you want what it appears you do but assuming your values are numeric to two decimal places then with Excel I suggest in D1 and copied down to suit:

```
=TEXT(100*A1;"000")&TEXT(100*B1;"000")&TEXT(100*C1;"000")
```

this results in text strings. Should you want numeric output for further processing then a [double unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500747/meaning-of-two-minus-signs-together-double-unary) can be applied:

```
=--(TEXT(100*A1;"000")&TEXT(100*B1;"000")&TEXT(100*C1;"000"))
```

In the latter case Excel will automatically strip any leading zeros. In the former case (should a number less than `1` be a possibility) the [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function preserves leading zeros.

Multiplication by `100` is to scale up the numbers to remove the decimal separators.

If the numbers are text then they may be [concatenated](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) and the commas removed with [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332):

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A1&B1&C1;",";"")
```

The above results in text strings which again may be converted with the double unary operator.